# Exception when trying to use saved Spark ML model for distributed computations with SHAP

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-synapse, apache-spark-ml

I am having this error

> Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference
> SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation.
> SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run
> on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

and

> PicklingError: Could not serialize object: Exception: It appears that you are attempting to reference SparkContext from a broadcast variable, action, or transformation. SparkContext can only be used on the driver, not in code that it run on workers. For more information, see SPARK-5063.

I have a saved LightGBM spark model which I want to use with SHAP package to get explanations of my predictions.

```
# loading LightGBM model
from synapse.ml.lightgbm import LightGBMClassificationModel
import shap

loaded_model = LightGBMClassificationModel.loadNativeModelFromFile(model_path) 

# Custom predict_proba method

assembler = VectorAssembler(handleInvalid="keep",
                                        inputCols=features,
                                        outputCol="features")

def spark_to_pandas(X):
        return spark.createDataFrame(X)
        
def predict_proba(X):
    
    sdf = assembler.transform(spark_to_pandas(X).select(*features))
    getNegative = F.udf(lambda x: float(x[0]), FloatType())
    getPositive = F.udf(lambda x: float(x[1]), FloatType())

    predictions = (
        loaded_model.transform(sdf)
        .select("probability")
        .withColumn("0", getNegative(F.col("probability")))
        .withColumn("1", getPositive(F.col("probability")))
        .select("0", "1")
    )
    return predictions.toPandas()

# Creating SHAP explainer

explainer = shap.KernelExplainer(model=predict_proba, 
                                 data=data_explainer.select(*features).limit(100).toPandas())

# Trying to get explanations

def explain_df(explainer, df):
    return [e.tolist() for e in explainer.shap_values(df)[1]]

explain = F.udf(lambda x: list(explain_df(explainer, x)), ArrayType(ArrayType(DoubleType())))

gr = datap.groupBy('_partition').agg(F.collect_list('features').alias('features'))
```

The last action doesn't work apparently because I am trying to use a spark model. This method works with sklearn models.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and discovered that Synapse ML has its [own explainers built in](https://microsoft.github.io/SynapseML/docs/features/responsible_ai/Interpretability%20-%20Explanation%20Dashboard/). The documentation is severely lacking, however. The alternative if you really need to use the shap package is to re-build the model with the lightgbm package—you'd just need to convert the Synapse ML LightGBMClassifier hyperparameters to the format accepted by lightgbm.